# How can i track which page called the current page to route back

Tags: angular

I have a Angular App which has pages that have grids and from the row the user can navigate to the detail page and once he is done, i have a back button on page to allow user to return to grid. In my case it became an issue which required me to keep track of the index of row clicked as well as the offset so un return user could return to that row on grid.
That all wored fine via this code

```
   this.state$
      .pipe(
       takeWhile(_ => this.alive),
       )
       .subscribe(state => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/Farm/FarmList', {state});
      });
```

Problem for me is that I now have the issue the my user ends up on the detail page and he did not come from the /Farm/FarmList route. So is there a simple way to get the path / Route from where a user came to this Page ?

When i use

```
this.location.back();
```

The navigation to the calling Page works as desired, but i lose my info on the index and the offset which is stored in the state variable.

Comment: You only want to 1 level back from current router to previous route ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different options:
1 - you can set selected row id or index in router params or query params and when you use the back button or navigate from other component you can point right to selected row with `this.route.snapshot.params.rowIndex;`

2- you can use a service provided in the module or root and save your state in a bahviorSubject or a state management libs like NGRX or Akita

Comment: Thanks, my {state} keeps track for me of filters and offset etc so thats not the problem. I am wondering how i can get the URL of the page that routed to me as it can be different. I have for example a grid called followups, that is on a customer, home page and vender form. So if my user selects from any of these pages i want to return to that page not a preset page